# orderby or orderbyDescending on Expression column not working in LINQ

Tags: linq-to-entities

```
var q4 = await dbentity.tbltest.Where(v => v.Nvcode == vcode)
                               .OrderByDescending(o => Convert.ToInt32(o.Period.Substring(5, 4)))
                               .Select(a => new { Period = a.Period, Year = Convert.ToInt32(a.Period.Substring(5, 4)) })
                               .Distinct()
                               .ToListAsync();
```

Above query return

```
Period     Year
2012-2013, 2013
2019-2020, 2020 
2013-2018, 2018
2007-2008, 2008
```

I want to sort above on Year i.e See below

```
Period     Year
2019-2020, 2020 
2013-2018, 2018
2012-2013, 2013
2007-2008, 2008
```

`Orderby` and `OrderbyDescending` not working in Linq to achieve above output.

Comment: You don't need the `Convert.ToInt32` in the `OrderByDescending` and your code should work. You need to show more details.

Comment: I need to use below code  for getting orderbydesc  by year, year is expression column
           foreach (var i in q4) {
                period.Add(i.Year, i.Period);
            }
            var jy = "";
            int y = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < period.Count; i++)//get  maximum Jamabandi-Year value for year
            {

                if (period.ElementAt(i).Key > y)
                {
                    y = period.ElementAt(i).Key;
                    jy = period.ElementAt(i).Value;
                }
            }